# Animation working fine in 4.2 but with an error in 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

This might be a bit long, but I will be so clear while explaining.

I'm developing an app which basically consists of a layout, with two relative layouts. When you click any of the two layouts, the second layout, expands or shrinks deppending of its actual visibility.

This is the layout:

[image]

This is the code that listens for any click on "main" or on "child" to expand/shrink:

```
    public void toggleAmagar(View v){
        View parent = (View) v.getParent();
        View child = parent.findViewById(R.id.child);
        Log.d("debugging","toggle amagar. Child visibility is :"+child.getVisibility()+". Clickable? Child: "+child.isClickable()+". Parent: "+v.isClickable());
        ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(child, 500);
        child.startAnimation(expandAni);
    }
```

And this is the animation class:

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
private View mAnimatedView;
private LayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;
private boolean mIsVisibleAfter = false;
private boolean mWasEndedAlready = false;

public ExpandAnimation(View view, int duration) {
    setDuration(duration);
    mAnimatedView = view;
    mViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    // decide to show or hide the view
    mIsVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

    mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
    mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0- view.getHeight()) : 0);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    Log.d("debugging","aplicant. Visible = "+this.mAnimatedView.getVisibility());
    mAnimatedView.setClickable(false);
    if (this.hasEnded()){
        mAnimatedView.setClickable(true);
        View pare = (View) mAnimatedView.getParent();
        View germa = (View) pare.findViewById(R.id.main);
        germa.setClickable(true);
    } else {
        mAnimatedView.setClickable(false);
        View pare = (View) mAnimatedView.getParent();
        View germa = (View) pare.findViewById(R.id.main);
        germa.setClickable(false);
    }
    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

    // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
    } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
            mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        mWasEndedAlready = true;
    }
}
```

This is what happens in Android 2.3:
[image]

These are the logs generated:

**LOG A:**

```
03-17 13:57:17.509: D/debugging(403): toggle amagar. Child visibility is :0. Clickable? Child: true. Parent: true
03-17 13:57:17.521: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:17.549: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:17.619: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:17.699: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:17.789: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:17.929: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:18.119: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 13:57:18.189: D/debugging(403): aplicant. Visible = 8
```

**LOG B**

```
03-17 13:57:45.439: D/debugging(403): toggle amagar. Child visibility is :8. Clickable? Child: true. Parent: true
```

Now I'm doing the same but in 4.2 (4.0.4 real device works the same way):
[image]

These are the logs:

**LOG A:**

```
03-17 14:13:06.104: D/debugging(815): toggle amagar. Child visibility is :0. Clickable? Child: true. Parent: true
03-17 14:13:06.192: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:06.212: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:06.475: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:06.692: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:06.792: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 8
```

**LOG B:**

```
03-17 14:13:08.923: D/debugging(815): toggle amagar. Child visibility is :8. Clickable? Child: true. Parent: true
03-17 14:13:09.013: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:09.022: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:09.232: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:09.442: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:09.666: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
03-17 14:13:09.803: D/debugging(815): aplicant. Visible = 0
```

As you can see, the only difference, is that the second click isn't applying the animation on 2.3 device.

I've tested it on a real device with 2.3, and other with 4.0.4 and it's happening too. Those are virtualized.

If you need any more information ask me.

Oh, by the way, the setClickable() trick inside the Animation class, is to prevent users to double click and bug the animation and layout, in case you are wondering it.

Thank you.

Sergi

**Edit**
Tried with several SDKS:

- 2.2 -> Bug
- 2.3 -> Bug
- 4.2 -> OK
- 4.0 -> OK

**Edit 19/03**

Update: Still happening, and I can't find out why.
Tomorrow I will keep debugging if noone finds an answer before... Thanks.